# Building Error: removing attribute android:textIsSelectable from <TextView>

Tags: android, eclipse, build, textview

When I built an old Android project in Eclipse today, I encountered an error which description is some like as below.

note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:textIsSelectable from 
activity_my.xml /my_project/res/layout  line 125    Android AAPT Problem

The project building worked fine. And I have not made any change in code. The only difference is that now I use a newer Build Tools revision 23.0.0.

Does it mean that a TextView can not set attribute:textIsSelectable to true while it has set value for attribute:id according rules of the newer Build Tools?

Any tips? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes now I found how to work around this problem after studying myself. 
Just change the value of android:minSdkVersion in AndroidManifest.xml from 10 to 11 or anyelse bigger.

But I wonder why building worked well with the old Build Tools even the android:minSdkVersion is 9 or 10.